# Only show comments on story pages in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-comments

I have a view set up for mysite.com/blog which pulls story nodes and prints them out. Right now it prints the comments after each story. What I want it to do is only print out the comments when you click through to the single story page.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you use the views module ? and/or content-type ?  ... if you are familiar with creating tpl.php files for the story content type: you can set in the story-tpl.php that he doesn't have to print out the comments when it is only a $teaser is shown.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it without any custom code, then within view you can select the row-style and then from fields section select title, body, date and user fields. And then style them accordingly.

If you want through custom code, let me know.